# Handling checkbox status using IF in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Im learning PHP and trying to print a message based on checkbox check and uncheck.but im getting only else part when im trying to check checkbox .here is the php code .Let me know where im going wrong.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function on_callPhp()
    {
        if(this.checked) {
            document.write("<?php echo php_func_c();?>");
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("<?php echo php_func_uc();?>");
        }
    }
    </script>

    <input type="checkbox" name="hit_val" value="hit" onchange="on_callPhp()">

    <?php
    function php_func_c()
    {
        echo "CHECKED";
    }

    function php_func_uc()
    {
        echo "UNCHECKED";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- The name `on_callPhp` seems to suggest that you think JavaScript will call PHP in that function. But that is not true. When PHP runs, it executes both `php_func_c` and `php_func_uc` in order to generate the strings you want to have. When PHP has finished running, the page is rendered in the browser. When the user checks the checkbox, no interaction with PHP is happening any more.
- `this` does not refer to the checkbox. You can pass `this` as function argument instead.
- Don't use `document.write` and certainly not in an event handler: in the latter case it will completely wipe out the page contents. Use `console.log` instead for debugging. Then when you are ready for it, you can do something more useful, like showing some other page content.

Here is the corrected code, although I left the name `on_callPhp` unchanged. Use a different name:

```
function on_callPhp(chkbox) // <-- notice the parameter
{
    if(chkbox.checked) { // <-- check the argument, not `this`
        console.log("<?php echo php_func_c();?>");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("<?php echo php_func_uc();?>");
    }
}
```

The `onchange` attribute can pass `this` to the function:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hit_val" value="hit" onchange="on_callPhp(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline event handlers (`onchange="..."`)  cause trouble like this, the same applies to `document.write`. instead use JS to manipulate the DOM:

```
  // HTML
 <input type="checkbox" id="hit" />
 <div id="output"></div>

  // JS
  const hit = document.querySelector("#hit");
  const output = document.querySelector("#output");

  hit.addEventListener("change", function() {
     output.textContent = hit.checked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked";
  });
```